# CSS only toggle switch not working in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to have a toggle switcher instead of checkboxes on ReactJS using pure CSS. The switch renders as how it should but nothing happens when it is clicked. The switch does not work as it should, but works when used without React.

```
<div className="switch">
   <input id="toggler-1" className="toggler toggler-round" type="checkbox" />
   <label for="toggler-1"></label>
</div>

.toggler {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.toggler + label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

input.toggler-round + label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -ms-border-radius: 60px;
  -o-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
}
input.toggler-round + label:before, input.toggler-round + label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
}
input.toggler-round + label:before {
  right: 1px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -ms-border-radius: 60px;
  -o-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.4s;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}
input.toggler-round + label:after {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -ms-border-radius: 100%;
  -o-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.4s;
  -o-transition: margin 0.4s;
  transition: margin 0.4s;
}
input.toggler-round:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #8ce196;
}
input.toggler-round:checked + label:after {
  margin-left: 60px;
}
```

I am not sure what is causing this. Is this sort of features not supported in React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the react docs:

```
Since JSX is JavaScript, identifiers such as class and for are discouraged as 
XML attribute names. Instead, React DOM components expect DOM property names 
like className and htmlFor, respectively.
```

Make sure you are using `htmlFor` instead of `for`

```
<div className="switch">
   <input id="toggler-1" className="toggler toggler-round" type="checkbox" />
   <label htmlFor="toggler-1"></label>
</div>
```

I tested it in js.fiddle, but the transition length exceeds the button length, which is the case for both the pure html/css case and with react. Yet, the toggle is now working:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/)